# Fundamental principles of Counting help

Tags: combinatorics

So basically I need a kind mathematician to confirm something. Here is the question I failed at solving.

Q: If there are two positive summands for 7, how many number of **integer** solutions are there?

Obviously if we did this manually there is 6 if order mattered, but my book gives me this very confusing solution. It says we can get 6 with w1 + w2 = 7 where w1, w2 >0. I tried plugging the answer my book gave me into C(n+r-1,r) but I get 8 and not 6..What values should I be using in relation to the restriction w1, w2 >0?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/804800/how-do-i-solve-this-discrete-math-problem-in-the-picture/804816#804816

Comment: (2+6−1,6) does not equal 6, which is the number of ways to make 7 given 2 numbers..Are you sure?

Comment: The number of non-negative solutions of $y_1+y_2+\cdots +y_r=n$ is $\binom{n+r-1}{n}$. For $n=5$, and $r=2$, we get $\binom{6}{5}=6$.

Comment: why does 7C2 not work?

Comment: You forgot to take into account zero (it all depends on what you count: positive solutions or nonegative solutions).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a small problem, and we can first *just do it*. Two positive integers sum to $7$. What can they be? They can be

1. $1 + 6 = 7$
2. $2 + 5 = 7$
3. $3 + 4 = 7$
4. $4 + 3 = 7$
5. $5 + 2 = 7$
6. $6 + 1 = 7$

And that's it. In fact, once we've chosen on integer, the other is forced. How many first choices do we have? We have exactly $6$. So that's another way of viewing it.

I think the way you are trying to interpret it works like this. You want to count positive integer solutions to $x_1 + x_2 = 7$, where $x_i$ are both at least $1$. We might think of this as having $7$ balls, and there are two boxes, and at the end of the day each box must have at least 1 ball.

So let's put a ball in each box - no problem - since each box will have at least 1 ball. Now we have $5$ left, to distribute however we want into the two boxes. We can represent this as a combination if we use the following type of representation: `oo|ooo` might mean the first box has $2$ balls, then there's a seperator, and then the second box has $3$ balls. Each representation consisting of $5$ circles and $1$ line gives us a way of putting $5$ balls into $2$ boxes.

How many different representations of $5$ circles and $1$ line are there? There are $ {6 \choose 1} = 6$ (six slots, one of them is a line), or equivalently $6 \choose 5$ (six slots, five of them are balls).

More generally, the same argument works for the number of nonnegative solutions to $x_1 + \ldots + x_r = k$. We count the number of representations consisting of $k$ circles and $(r-1)$ lines (the minus one is to avoid [fencepost error](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Off-by-one_error#Fencepost_error), like above). How many solutions are there? There are $k + r - 1 \choose r - 1$, from there being $k + r - 1$ slots and choosing the $r-1$ lines. Here, $r = 2$ and $k=5$.

Still more generally, if we have $x_1 + \ldots + x_r = k$ and we know that $x_i \geq y_i$ for each $i$ (for some nonnegative integers $y_i$), then we first just go ahead and give each of the boxes its minimum to reduce it to the problem just above. This leads to the number of nonnegative solutions to $x_1 + \ldots + x_r = k - (y_1 + \ldots + y_r)$, which is what we just covered.

In this case, we have $x_1 + x_2 = 7$ where $x_1, x_2 \geq 1$, which reduces to $x_1 + x_2 = 5$ for general nonnegative $x_i$.